# Angular ng-repeat object, if-else, first letter of the key

Tags: angularjs, if-statement, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I try to get a collection of the cities with alphabet sorting.
I have a list of objects which looks so `[{city: 'Liverpool', count: 1000, country: 'United Kingdom'}, ...]`

I want get items this way

```
L
Liverpool (1000)
London (2000)
M
Manchester (500)
N
Newport (800)
Northampton (90)
```

Maximum that I've could - I get just the list city-count without Letter.
I think I'm going wrong way, but I have no idea about a correct algorytm.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/valsaven/ysf56w48/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own `filter`, then update your html:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('appCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.cities = [{
      city: 'London',
      count: 2000,
      country: 'United Kingdom'
    }, {
      city: 'Liverpool',
      count: 1000,
      country: 'United Kingdom'
    }, {
      city: 'Manchester',
      count: 500,
      country: 'United Kingdom'
    }, {
      city: 'Newport',
      count: 800,
      country: 'United Kingdom'
    }, {
      city: 'Northampton',
      count: 90,
      country: 'United Kingdom'
    }];
    $scope.cities = $filter('alphsort')($scope.cities);
  })
  .filter('alphsort', function() {
    return function(input) {
      var result = {};
      angular.forEach(input, function(val, index) {
        var key = val.city.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        result[key] = result[key] || [];
        result[key].push(val);
      });
      return result;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">

  <div>
    <div ng-repeat="(alph,list) in cities track by alph">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <strong ng-bind="alph"></strong>
        </li>
        <li ng-repeat="item in (list | orderBy: 'city' ) track by $index">
          <p>
            <a href="javascript:;" ng-bind="item.city"></a>
            <span>({{item.count}})</span>
          </p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Oh, I see. That's work for me!
I hadn't read about the filters yet. That's really so simple. I've racked my brains for 4 hours, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look at angular filters

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

You can set up something like:

`<div ng-repeat="city in cities | orderBy : expression : reverse">`